# Displaying sub-array in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In  my Angular app I have the following `<select>` element that is populated like so:

**HTML**

```
<select name="device[ [[$index]] ]" ng-model="selectedModel" ng-change="loadModelImage(selectedModel)">
    <option value="">Model</option>
    <option ng-repeat="model in manufacturerModels" value="[[model.id]]">[[model.model]]</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.manufacturerModels = $filter('filter')($scope.models, {manufacturer_id: manufacturerId});
```

The above AngularJS snippet will return a JSON response of handset models stored in the API. *(I'd post an example here but each object is quite lengthy).*

Anyway, inside each 'model' is a sub-array of variants -- objects containing colours and memory sizes available for that device.

eg:

```
{
    model: "iPhone 6",
    manufacturer: "Apple",
    variants: [
        {
            color: "space grey",
            memory: "128GB"
        }
        {
            color: "gold",
            memory: "16GB"
        }
        {
            color: "space grey",
            memory: "64GB"
        }
    ]
}
```

**The Goal**

I'd like to know if it's possible (and if so, how) to populate the model dropdown's `<option>`'s with the variants in the name. So where it currently says `[[model.model]]` *(.model being the name)*, I need each option to say something like: "iPhone 6 space grey 128GB"

PS. Angular interpolation temp. changed to `[[ ]]` due to the same pages using mustachePHP.

Comment: Do you want a list that shows all model + variants combinations? If that's the case, you need to flatten your list before using it in the ng-repeat.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but you can divide the models in optgroups and then have an option for each variant within each model:

```
<select>
        <option value="">Model</option>
        <optgroup ng-repeat="model in data" label="{{model.model}}">
          <option ng-repeat="variant in model.variants" value="{{model}}">{{ model.model + '-' + variant.color }}</option>
        </optgroup>
</select>
```

Please see this plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/rPNaGXEi0m9rvNkzQuBJ?p=preview

Alternatively, you have to flatten your array:

```
$scope.flatten = function(){
      var out = [];
      angular.forEach($scope.data, function(d){
        angular.forEach(d.variants, function(v){
          out.push({model: d.model, variant: v.color})
        })
      })
      return out;
    }
```

And then you can use ngSelect:

```
<select ng-model="myColor" ng-options="model.variant group by model.model for model in flatten()">
   <option value=""> -- select -- </option>
</select>
```

Here's the updated Plnkr: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/rPNaGXEi0m9rvNkzQuBJ?p=preview

Comment: No idea why I didn't think of this... Bounty will be awarded in 19hrs

Comment: How do I rewrite this using ng-options and group by?

Comment: my `manufacturerModels` is a filtered version of `$scope.models` which retrieves all of the models from the API and filters the data on demand by passing in the selected manufacturer ID as the filter. `$scope.manufacturerModels = $filter('filter')($scope.models, { manufacturer_id: manufacturerId });` --- I don't know if this is the culprit but when I follow your flatten approach I get this error: http://goo.gl/MX5WXH

Comment: Don't know why that is happening, but you can flatten the `$scope.models` before applying your `manufacturer_id` filter or you can create a filter of your own that flattens the array/object

Answer (score 3):

This may not be the answer you're looking for, but AngularJS is always pushing you to work with view-models, meaning models tailored for the views.

Your example with the models & its nested variants is not a model which is tailored for the view you're trying to present, and so I would suggest creating a new model based on your current model.

This new model would have one entry per model per variant, and would be flat so that a single ng-repeat would easily iterate over them. You could even add a watch statement to "manufacturerModels", so that you can be sure the new model you create for the options ng-repeat is always up to date.

Another option, which would work with what you're trying to do would be to create a simple directive, which only copies its inner html without its tags, for example:

```
<noTags>someHtml</noTags> --> someHtml
```

I'll leave it to you to write this directive, as its fairly simple.

Then, to solve your problem you'd simply need to write a nested ng-repeat statement, something like this:

```
<select name="device[ [[$index]] ]" ng-model="selectedModel" ng-change="loadModelImage(selectedModel)">
    <option value="">Model</option>
    <noTags ng-repeat="model in manufacturerModels">
        <option ng-repeat="varient in model.varients" value="[[model.id]]">[[model.model]] [[varient.color]] [[varient.memory]]</option>
    </noTags>
</select>
```

The rendered html should simply provide a long list of option tags which have all the options you want.

Comment: A `noTags` directive sounds appealing. Would you still recommend it?

Answer (score -2):

You need to use the 'ngOptions' directive for that purpose.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select
The directive can take either an array of options or a hash (object) of options.
And omit the 'ngRepeat' within 'option'.