# ngOptions bind from inner and outer array in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have the following array of objects and looking to bind my select options with first array item name combined with inner array item name without success.

**Array**

```
"Collections": [
                  {
                      "Name": "Collection1",
                      "Fields": [
                        {
                            "Name": "Field1"
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "Field2"
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "Field3"
                    }
                  ]
              },
              {
                  "Name": "Collection2",
                  "Fields": [
                    {
                        "Name": "Field1"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "Field2"
                    }
                  ]
              }
            ]
```

**Select**

```
<select ng-options=" collectionList.Name for collectionList in Collections" class="form-control" ng-model="selected">
```

**Expected Options**

```
<option value="">Collection1.Field1</option>
<option value="">Collection1.Field2</option>
<option value="">Collection1.Field3</option>
<option value="">Collection2.Field1</option>
<option value="">Collection2.Field2</option>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You might be able to work it by putting a more complex expression in the ng-options directive, but I personally would just transform the collection into a flat array and bind to that. It's not elegant, but it solves the problem.

Comment: I'm interested on more complex expression. Any example?

Comment: Not from me, because I wouldn't do that. I will defer to someone who would.

Comment: Here's a [question similar to yours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26957664/displaying-sub-array-in-ng-repeat) that might solve your problem. Basically, use `<optgroup>` to ngrepeat over your collection and then `<option>` to ngrepeat over the fields. Throw some upvotes over there if it helps.

Comment: Following on @Terminus suggestion, If you don't need to support IE8 or lower, you should be able to use an <ng-repeat> element in place of <optgroup> if you specifically don't want optgroups in your select box.

Comment: i think this is not good to put more complex expression in ng-repeat. Better you can make manipulation in your json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this,

```
 <select ng-model='theModel'>
    <optgroup ng-repeat='group in collection' label="{{group.Name}}">
        <option ng-repeat='veh in group.Fields'>{{veh.Name}}</option>
    </optgroup>
 </select>
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/CY0aZjXZzhL0F3gPVce2?p=preview)

Comment: I need my model should return "Collection1.Field2" like this output when the option is selected.

Comment: @Vicky just get the model and find the parent and use that as scope variable

Comment: I was not able to get unfortunately, any chance you can show me on the fiddle?

Comment: @Vicky https://plnkr.co/edit/KfrZj0NkWs5iYPWbfq3B?p=preview , please mark as answer

Comment: @Vicky sorted ?